# Select substring from column but each record has different pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have column with different pattern of string for each records let's call it [Description]. Here's the sample of records

```
  [Description]
 -qwetw MANN/1234556/DATE/030621/B/C/ACC/DIFF+AA11000532
 -qwerty 123456789/06/29/2021/ACC./DONE/CLOSED+06+AA11001234
 -qwert 123456789101213/-/BACK/300621/Rekening/Tutup+06+ZZZ21001123A
```

I want only pick the last number order - so the output would be:

```
[Description]
 -11000532
 -11001234
 -21001123
```

Is there any function how to get it?

Thanks

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is tricky, as it is having alphabets also as part of the order number.

I am assuming your datatype is VARCHAR(4000) and accordingly, I have applied substring in the end with 4000, to make it simpler in the end.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(Description varchar(4000))

  insert into @table values

('-qwetw MANN/1234556/DATE/030621/B/C/ACC/DIFF+AA11000532')
,('-qwert 123456789101213/-/BACK/300621/Rekening/Tutup+06+ZZZ21001123A')
,('-qwerty 123456789/06/29/2021/ACC./DONE/CLOSED+06+AA11001234');

SELECT SUBSTRING(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Description),1,CHARINDEX('+',REVERSE(Description)))),PATINDEX('%[1-9]%',REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Description),1,CHARINDEX('+',REVERSE(Description))))),4000) as ordernumber FROM @table
```

| ordernumber |
| --- |
| 11000532 |
| 21001123A |
| 11001234 |

Comment: hay @venkataraman thanks for your help. your code is almost correct but still got 'A' char on the second row. I expected all the numbers only because for target column is integer datatype.

Comment: @Paktelo, so, you want to replace any alphabets in the order number

Comment: yup, just the number only

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solutions.

First solution is for SQL Server 2017 onwards.

It is working by implementing the following steps:

1. It is tokenizing column value as XML.
2. Last token is our goal, i.e. `(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]`
3. TRIM() removes unwanted chars.

Second solution is for SQL Server 2012. It is much more involving.

**SQL 2017**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Tokens VARCHAR(4000));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('-qwetw MANN/1234556/DATE/030621/B/C/ACC/DIFF+AA11000532'),
('-qwert 123456789101213/-/BACK/300621/Rekening/Tutup+06+ZZZ21001123A'),
('-qwerty 123456789/06/29/2021/ACC./DONE/CLOSED+06+AA11001234');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '+'
    , @CharsToRemove VARCHAR(100) = 'AZ';

SELECT ID, tokens
    , TRIM(@CharsToRemove FROM token) AS Result
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML))) AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)'))) AS t2(token);
```

**SQL 2012**

```
SELECT ID, tokens
    , (
   SELECT SUBSTRING(token, number, 1)
   FROM @tbl AS c
      CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DISTINCT number
         FROM master..spt_values
         WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(token)
      ) V
   WHERE c.ID = p.ID
   FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
)
.query('for $x in /root/r
        return if (xs:int($x) instance of xs:int) then $x
         else ()') 
.query('/r/text()').value('.', 'BIGINT') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS p
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML))) AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(256)'))) AS t2(token);
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| ID |                               tokens                                |  Result  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|  1 | -qwetw MANN/1234556/DATE/030621/B/C/ACC/DIFF+AA11000532             | 11000532 |
|  2 | -qwert 123456789101213/-/BACK/300621/Rekening/Tutup+06+ZZZ21001123A | 21001123 |
|  3 | -qwerty 123456789/06/29/2021/ACC./DONE/CLOSED+06+AA11001234         | 11001234 |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```